# ios - Is keychain same for production and adhoc app?

Tags: ios, iphone, keychain

Can anybody please give me some insight in this.

Is keychain for same app is same in production and adhoc or debug apps?

Also same questions for advertising identifier. Will it be same for production, adhoc or debug apps, unless I do not reset it in the same device?

I have experienced some issues regarding this. I store a value in keychain and read it. When testing in debgu, adhoc and enterprise provisioning profile, seems I got a difference keychain access.

I ran some experiment in Apple Beta testing service and found, YES, in beta testing app and and in debug app, I do not get the same keychain values. Its different !!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I test access to a keychain property after update via the AppStore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709897/how-do-i-test-access-to-a-keychain-property-after-update-via-the-appstore)